# Require fieldset after checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, required

I just started learning HTML/CSS, javascript and jQuery last week and would very much appreciate some help. 
I have created a form with a checkbox (id #ship_to_billing) and then a fieldset (id #shipping_info) containing 5 text fields. Using JQuery I've set it up so that, if that if the checkbox is checked, it toggles the other fields and hides them. But, I cannot figure out how to additionally require one or the other, either the checkbox has to be checked or all of the text fields within the fieldset must be completed. I do not need an alert. Please help!

Thank you all in advance, Susan

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#product-options" data-           
toggle="modal">Buy This!</a>                                        
    <div class="modal hide fade" id="product-options">                    
        <div class="modal-header center">
             <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
                <h3>When, Where and How?</h3>
         </div>
            <div class="modal-body l-m"> 
            {% include 'datepicker' %}
            <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="properties[ship_to_billing]" value="" />                          
            <label for="ship_to_billing" style="max-width:335px;">
            <input id="ship_to_billing" type="checkbox" name="properties[Ship to Billing Address]" value="Yes" {% if properties.ship_to_billing %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
            <font size=1>Check here to have items shipped to your billing address (collected during checkout). Otherwise please fill out the information below.</font>
            </label><br /> 
            </p>                        
          <div class="fieldgroup" id="shipping_info">
            <label for="shipping_name">Name of Recipient:</label>      
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="shipping_name" placeholder="Name" name="properties[Recipient]" required="required" />                                 
            <p>
            <label for="address_street">Shipping Address:</label>
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="address_street" placeholder="Street Address" name="properties[Address]" required="required" />
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="address_city" placeholder="City" name="properties[City]" required="required" />
            <input class="input-medium" type="text" id="address_province" placeholder="State" name="properties[State]" required="required" />
            <input class="input-medium" type="text" id="address_zip" placeholder="Zip Code" name="properties[Zip]" required="required" />
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>
          <label for="gift_msg">Gift Message :</label>                                
          <textarea id="gift_msg" placeholder="Please type your message" name="properties[Gift Message]" rows="4" cols="45"></textarea> 
          </p>                              
       </div>

       <div class="modal-footer">
           <div class="btn-group">
                <button href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" onclick="return validateShipping();" class="btn btn-primary" id="addtocart">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>              
        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script>
$('#ship_to_billing').change(function(){
$('#shipping_info').toggle('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: So am I right in assuming that if the checkbox is checked then the fields disappear? Sorry if this is a little pedantic ;)

Comment: @ChrisKempen I believe the checkbox is initially checked.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. What do you mean by "additionally require"? The checkbox has to be checked or the fields have to be completed why?

Comment: @matija - Not necessarily, doesn't it rely on the `if` statement? Also, @susan, is this a jQuery question, or a server-side validation question?

Comment: Hello there! The checkbox is unchecked upon opening the form. Then, if it's clicked, the fieldset toggles and hides. But as it is currently the customer can still submit the form without filling out anything. I've been able to require everything but not either or. ?

Comment: Sorry, just saw the other questions. Why I need the checkbox checked or the fields is because I'm asking customers if they want their items shipped to their billing address (check the box) or, if not, then they must tell me the address they need it shipped to by filling out the fields in the fieldset.

Comment: Also, answering Chris, this is a jQuery question. Sorry for not being clear and thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client-side validation is always going to fall second-best to server-side validation, as the user can always disable Javascript or force-post nonsense that can override browser ability, but your server can't be fooled as easily! That said, you're on the right track, although I'd be tempted to fix it up a little...first, your HTML (abridged):

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="ship_to_billing" type="checkbox" name="properties" />
    <div class="fieldgroup" id="shipping_info">
        <input type="text" id="shipping_name" name="properties[Recipient]" />
        <input type="text" id="address_street" name="properties[Address]" />
        ...
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="return validateMyStuff();" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Next, your script, slightly more robust:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // this will run when the document's done loading...
    $(function(){
        $("#ship_to_billing").change(function(){
            // make sure of the checked state...
            // hide the fields if the checkbox is checked...
            // 'this' is the checkbox...
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) // fixed error here! ;)
                $("#shipping_info").hide();
            else
                $("#shipping_info").show();
        });
    });

    // validate the input, only if the checkbox is not checked...
    // this will be called when your submit button is clicked...
    function validateMyStuff() {
        if (!$("#ship_to_billing").is(":checked")) {
            // check to see that the other input fields have values...
            var inputs = $("#shipping_info input");
            var ready = true;
            inputs.each(function(){
                // 'this' is the current input we're validating...
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    ready = false;
                    return false; // exits jQuery '.each' function...
                }
            });
            if (!ready) {
                alert("You forgot to fill in something!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Well, that's the best interpretation I can give based on the limited information in the original question. Hope this helps! :)

***EDIT 1:***

My apologies! I left out a closing bracket `)` on line 10 of my JavaScript code! I've fixed the problem, and copy / pasting the code above into an HTML page seems to work fine. Remember to include your jQuery script above the rest of your scripts, and to put your scripts in the `<head>...</head>` section of your HTML.

Comment: This seems like it should be totally perfect and I thank you so much for taking the time to give me such a thorough answer!! But, alas, I just tried it and don't seem to be able to to make it work. I copied your JQuery exactly outside of switching the name of my submit button but it's not doing it! :-(  
Not sure if it will give you any more info but I edited my html above with the full section of this page and do want to mention it is within a form with syntax: <form action="/cart/add" method="post">
Thank you again!!

Comment: This actually doesn't even collapse my fieldgroup...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @susan...my apologies, there was a tiny error in my code, hope it's working closer to how you envisioned it now! ;)

Comment: This blows my mind, totally. First your wizard like genius but the effort and time you put into this is extraordinary. Thank you so much. Works!

Comment: Haaha thank you @susan, it's my pleasure! Good luck with the rest of your project! :)

Comment: LOL! You're the best @Sergio...never thought obsession-induced-insomnia would get me any kind of rep! :')

Answer (score 0):

As far as client-side validation, you could give all the inputs inside the `shipping_info` fieldset the [`required` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-required-attribute) like this

```
$('#shipping_info input').attr('required', true);
```

But this doesn't guarantee the fields will be filled, as the user can bypass this. So you have to check it server-side whatever you do.

Comment: This works, and so does required="required", but I can only figure out how to make them all required, don't have the syntax to do an either or scenario with JQuery.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, much appreciated. Also want to mention this is for a Shopify site so not sure server-side validation will be possible.